# Number the nodes of a Treeview control

Tags: c#, treeview

Is this possible to name the nodes of a Treeview control something like Matrix?

For Example:

```
Parent Node
   --> Child Node
       --> Grand child node
Other Parent Node
```

**To** (*Something like this*)

```
-- Node1
   --> Node11
       --> Node111
       --> Node112
         --> Node1121
   --> Node12
   --> Node13
-- Node2
```

I am adding the nodes and child nodes by Button click `btnAddNode` and `btnAddChildNode`

 Now I am just incrementing a counter value which is not catching whether the node is child or parent (*just incrementing*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is using these two simple methods. First is adding TreeNodes to the TreeView control and the second adds the child nodes to the already added nodes.

```
public void AddNode(TreeView parent, string text)
{
    if (parent != null)
    {
         parent.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(text + (parent.Nodes.Count + 1).ToString()));
    }
}
public void AddChildNode(TreeNode parent)
{
    if(parent != null)
    {
         string number = parent.Text;
         parent.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(number + (parent.Nodes.Count + 1).ToString()));   
    }
}
```

And to check if it's working you can do something like this:

```
AddNode(treeView1, "Node");
AddNode(treeView1, "Node");
AddNode(treeView1, "Node");
AddChildNode(treeView1.Nodes[0]);
AddChildNode(treeView1.Nodes[0]);
AddChildNode(treeView1.Nodes[0]);
AddChildNode(treeView1.Nodes[1]);
AddChildNode(treeView1.Nodes[2]);
AddChildNode(treeView1.Nodes[2]);
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I need to show some text too beside those numbers. See my edited question. Sorry for late request

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between btnAddNode and btnAddChildNode? Are the root nodes added with btnAddNode and all the other child nodes with btnAddChildNode?

Principally, you can use sth like the following code to find the depth of the node you are adding.

```
   counter = 0 ; 
   while (node.Parent != null)
   {
       node = node.Parent;
       counter++;
   }
```